# Can you upload Dragon Age Origins data into Dragon Age 2 on a different system?

Tags: ps3, dragon-age-inquisition, dragon-age-origins, dragon-age-2

I beat DAO on my ps3 and I'm moving in a couple months. I am unable to bring my ps3 with me so I will have to buy a different one. If I buy DA2, can I upload the DAO data to my DA2 on this different system? I want to play inquisition but I want to complete the tapestry first (I got day for free on origin).

If I am unable to do this, I have a follow up: do any decisions in DAO have an impact, whether it be significant or not, on the DA2 story?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can transfer your saves between PS3s.
You can either use the cloud to do this if you're a PS+ subscriber or you can use any USB external storage drive like a simple pen drive.

**Transfer your save to a pen drive (or similar):**

1. Go to *Game -> Saved Data Utility*. This is where all your saves are stored.
2. Browse to the right savegame and press triangle. And select Copy in the newly opened sidebar.
3. You’ll be prompted for the destination. Any external storage drive will do (like a USB stick or a memory card), save games aren’t so very big. Additionally, you can also transfer the save game to another user account.
4. Wait for the copying to finish, and you’re done!

**Transfer your save back to PS3:**

1. Go to *Game -> Saved Data Utility*.
2. Way at the top you’ll see your storage drives. Click on the one you need.
3. Just like before, select the desired savegame and press triangle. Then select Copy in the sidebar and choose to copy to your PlayStation 3’s hard drive.
4. Wait for it to finish copying, and you’re done!

[Source](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-back-up-and-import-ps3-game-saves/).

To use the PS+ cloud the process is exactly the same with the exception that you select *Online Storage* instead of your external USB storage drive.

Comment: This answer does a much better job explaining how to move the files than Dulkan's. Technically the 2nd part of the question was only if they couldn't move the files, but it wouldn't hurt to address it as well. Dulkan is right that there is very little difference.

Comment: @DCShannon Thank you for the praise. I've used my PS3 a lot in the past so I knew what he was looking for. However I've never played Dragon Age: Origins or Dragon Age II so I couldn't really comment on that :).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to transfer the savegame and import it into DA2, though I have no idea what options are available for a PS3 in this regard. If it's saved on the cloud on your PS or Origin-account, it's no hassle at all, otherwise you'll need some sort of medium(usb-stick?) the PS3 is compatible with to copy the savegame on.

However, you won't notice significant differences, the import will only provide some cameos and comments regarding your actions in DaO. It's a nice personal touch, but nothing essential and for DAI you can restore your DaO story via the tapestry anyway.

Comment: I'm trying to remember the biggest effect on DA2 from DAO. I think it might be who the king is, and where you encounter Alistair. This has very little effect on anything. If Zevran died in your DAO save, then you won't see him in DA2.